# Android 12 Splash Screen API

Tags: android, themes

where do you place the line:

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/...</item>
```

taken from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen) on the new Android 12 Splash Screen API?

Comment: It goes in the theme that you are using for your splash screen activity: "You can specify the following attributes in your Activity theme to customize the splash screen for your app"

Comment: When I place the line between the android:theme tags in my Manifest file it doesn't work

Comment: In your themes.xml not on the manifest

Comment: Thank you so much!